# Unable to Get value from MySQL and print to TextBox

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

So this method is supposed to get the ipaddress of the logged in user from a MySQL Database and print it to a textbox. However, I cant seem to get it right as the program just closes after I execute this method.

```
    public void readIPAddress()
    {
        string username = GlobalData._sharedUserName;
        String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString);

        conn.Open();
        queryStr = "";
        queryStr = "SELECT ipaddress FROM webappdemo.userregistration WHERE username=?username";
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", username);
        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (cmd.ExecuteReader().Read())
        {
            textBoxIPAddress.Text = reader["ipaddress"].ToString();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

If anyone could point out where I went wrong, I greatly appreciate your help!

Edit: After using try and catch I get this:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at ConnectToDataBase.Form2.readIPAddress() in C:\Users\ee\Dropbox\ConnectToDataBase\ConnectToDataBase\Form2.cs:line 95
```

Comment: use try catch to trace the exception if any, Why are you executing the command two times using `ExecuteReader`?

Comment: Suggestion: checkout [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelper.html) class. you may find it much easier to work with.

Comment: Comment for the edit : this code won't compile as `reader` is not defined

Comment: reader is defined outside of the method as

Comment: reader is defined outside of the method as             MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader reader;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Fix:

You are executing the command two times, using  `ExecuteReader` that's why you are getting such exception. If you execute the code like this means your code will works fine:

```
string queryStr = "SELECT ipaddress FROM webappdemo.userregistration WHERE username=@username";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            textBoxIPAddress.Text = reader["ipaddress"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Smart Fix:

Here you are fetching a single value from the database in such situations you need not to use reader at all.  you can simply access those value by using `ExecuteScalar()` method, which will give you the required object. if so You can use the following code:

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    using(MySqlCommand cmd= new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", username);
        conn.Open();
        object ipAddress= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (ipAddress!= null) 
           textBoxIPAddress.Text = ipAddress.ToString();
        else
           textBoxIPAddress.Text = "No data found";
    }
}
```

Hope that you wont forget to add `MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` to the using section

Answer (score 0):

you are executing reader two times by calling `ExecuteReader()`, why you need Reader here, if you only need one value from database. use `ExecuteScalar` that will return first value of the first record from the result. Sample code:

```
try
{
    string query = "SELECT ipaddress FROM webappdemo.userregistration WHERE username = @username";
    string connString =ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebAppConnString"].ToString();
    using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@username", username);

            connection.Open();
            object ip= command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (ip != null) {
              textBoxIPAddress.Text = ip.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{
    // do something with the exception

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
    cmd.ExecuteReader(); //Executing reader and not assigning to anything

    while (cmd.ExecuteReader().Read()) //Executing reader again and not assigning to anything again
    {
        //There is nothing assigned to reader.
        textBoxIPAddress.Text = reader["ipaddress"].ToString(); 
    }
```

Quick Solution:

```
    //assuming reader is defined
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read()) //read from the reader
    {
        textBoxIPAddress.Text = reader["ipaddress"].ToString(); 
    }
```

Alternative Solutions using [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelper.html):

```
try {
    object ip = MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connString, query, new MySqlParameter[] {
                                    new MySqlParameter("?username", username) 
                                }));
    if (ip != null) {
        textBoxIPAddress.Text = ip.ToString();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // do something with the exceptio
}
```

If you insist on using reader:

```
//assuming reader is defined
reader = MySqlHelper.ExecuteReader(connString, query, new MySqlParameter[] {
                                new MySqlParameter("?username", username) 
                            }));
while (reader.Read()) //read from the reader
{
    textBoxIPAddress.Text = reader["ipaddress"].ToString(); 
}
```

Note: the above code is just typed in here and may contain syntax errors. take this a a guideline.